# Anaconda Navigator start widow can't resize or minimise

Tags: python, dpi, navigator

[text](https://stackoverflow[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xshJ.png).com)

when I open up anaconda navigator the options to exit, minimise or resize disappear from the top of the screen and the bottom toolbar also disappears. The navigator consumes the whole screen and am unable to gain access to other apps unless I quit the app I have tried unchecking DPI scaling but no luck, alt f7 also does not help, any ideas?

As above, would like to gain access to the size of the navigator terminal